# Scala plugin incompatible with Intellij 2018.3.3: Cannot select Scala in "New Project"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I cannot select Scala in "New Project" in Intellij.
The Scala plugin is incompatible with Intellij Ultimate 2018.3.3. It was hard to find out though. Should I now really downgrade Intellij to a previous version? If so, which?

Here we see that the plugin is installed:

[image: Scala plugin is installed]

Scala does not appear on the list:

[image]

Only when going to the "Installed" tab of the plugins, we see the incompatibility:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the third image (where you get through Help->Find Action->"Plugins") you see the tab "Updates(2)" (even though I just installed the Scala plugin). Updating the Scala plugin fixes the issue.